# Remove duplicates from ArcGIS geocoded results

Tags: arcgis-online, geocoding

I'm adding an address search feature in my app using the ArcGIS findAddressCandidates API. I've found for some searches I get a load of repetitive results and I would like to filter them down to something that won't confuse the user. For example, the following URL (token value removed) returns eight results

https://geocode-api.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?address=auckland&f=pjson&sourceCountry=NZ&outFields=AddNum,StAddr,City,Region,Addr_type,status,Place_addr,Rank,LongLabel

Six of them look like this with slightly different locations, city/region and ranks.

```
{
        "address": "Auckland",
        "location": {
            "x": 174.74304,
            "y": -36.85582
        },
        "score": 100,
        "attributes": {
            "status": "T",
            "LongLabel": "Auckland, NZL",
            "Addr_type": "Locality",
            "Place_addr": "Auckland",
            "Rank": 19,
            "AddNum": "",
            "StAddr": "",
            "City": "",
            "Region": "Auckland"
        },
        "extent": {
            "xmin": 173.82404,
            "ymin": -37.77482,
            "xmax": 175.66204,
            "ymax": -35.93682
        }
    },
```

Another looks like like that but has a lat/long about 200km south east of the others, and the last is in the same central city area as most of them but has a different LongLabel "Auckland, Quay St, Auckland Central, Auckland, 1010, NZL"

It might be worth nothing that some of the results had a City value and some have a Region value, but they are all addr_type=Locality apart from the sone with a unique LongLabel which is a POI

My code currently matches all them by LongLabel and then takes the one with the highest rank value, but that removes the one that is 200km away and leaves the one with the street names and on a map off the area the two remaining points are effectively the same. My next option is to use the extent and any overlapping results get filtered by rank.

Is there a setting I can use with ArcGIS findAddressCandidates to stop it returning lots of "Auckland, NZL" results, or an algorithm to usefully filter them down after I receive them?